# While changing content under the HTML Head tab in design in magento configuration page not changing after updation? what will be the issue?

Tags: magento, web

While changing content under the HTML Head tab in design in magento configuration page not changing after updation? what will be the issue?

the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/2hhec6

Comment: it is not much understandable, you should explain in brief. is configuration values for design are not saving ? Or these are not applying on frontend ?

Comment: Did you flush caches?

Comment: of course i flushed them.. but it remains same Dushyant Joshi..

Answer (score 0):

Check the values for different scopes. (from "Current Configuration Scope" drop down)